# Encountered race even after using std::atomic types

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, atomic

Can you please tell me if the following code is thread safe?

I think I am encountering a race condition, because Task2 does not get executed even though I have set the value of params.b to be true from the GUI.

```
struct params { 
    params() {}
    ~params() {}
    atomic_bool a;
    atomic_bool b;
};

struct driver { 
    driver() {}
    ~driver() {}

    params myParams;

    void tFun() {
        while (1) {
            if (myParams.a) { /* DoTask1 */ }
            if (myParams.b) { /* DoTask2 */ }
        }
    }

    void DoSome() {
        std::thread t(&driver::tFun, this);
        t.detach();
        while (1) {
            myParams.a = fromGui.val;
            myParams.b = fromGui.val;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    driver myDriver;
    myDriver.DoSome();
    return 0;
}
```

Please execuse my 'fromGui.val' usage, it is supposed to indicate that this value will be loaded from the GUI.

Comment: I pared your example down a bit so it could be seen more easily in one glance (only non-line-break change was to shift the all-public classes to structs).

Comment: Great! Should have thought of it myself, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation I can see is that there is a race between `fTun()` function and `DoSome()`:

For example:

```
1. DoSome() sets a,b true 
2. tFun() executes in while loop, as a is true, it starts DoTask1
2. DoSome() sets a,b to false
3. tFun() finishes DoTask1 and come to check myParams.b which is false;
   DoTask2 is ignored!!
4. loop continues to step 1
```

If you always set a,b to true, then there is no race to compare with, tasks `DoTask1 & DoTask2` should both be executed

Comment: While testing my example, I had both params set to true from the GUI, so I doubt that DoSome would set b to false

Comment: Debug or print out myParams.a, myParams.b in tFun() function. if both set to true, no race should happen as they execute in sequence.

Answer (score -2):

I can't find any real race conditions in here, but I believe this code might not run properly on ALL OSes.

Let's see putting some yields fix the problem.

```
void tFun() {
    while (1) {
         bool nop = false;
         if (myParams.a) { /* DoTask1 */ }
         else { nop = true; }
         if (myParams.b) { /* DoTask2 */ }
         else { nop = true; }
         if (nop) { std::this_thread::yield(); }
    }
}

void DoSome() {
    std::thread t(&driver::tFun, this);
    t.detach();
    while (1) {
        myParams.a = fromGui.val;
        myParams.b = fromGui.val;
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}
```